# How can i make multiple requests using the useSWR hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, fetch-api, swr

I'm trying to make multiple calls using the `useSWR` hook but I'm getting an error that says:

> Cannot read properties of null (reading 'destroy')

```js
async function FetchApi(url) {
  const response = await fetch(url);
  const result = await response.json();
  if (res.ok) {
    return result;
  }
  throw new Error(result.message);
}

function Fetch(url) {
  const { data, error, isLoading } = useSWR(url, FetchApi);
  return { data, error, isLoading };
}
```

```js
export default function page() {
  const request1 = Fetch("endpoint1");
  const request2 = Fetch("endpoint2");

  if (request1.isLoading || request2.isLoading) return "Loading...";
  if (request1.error) {
    toast.error(error.message);
  }
  if (request2.error) {
    toast.error(error.message);
  }

  console.log(request1.data, request2.data);
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can create `fetcher` function for something like this:

```
function fetcher(...urls) {
  const f = (u) => fetch(u).then((r) => r.json());

  if (urls.length > 1) {
    return Promise.all(urls.map(f));
  }
  return f(urls);
}
```

You can read full discussion [here](https://github.com/vercel/swr/discussions/786)